# Unit testing static utility class

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

How can I unit test static method within a static class?

Having this code:

```
public class AddressConverter {
    public static BillingAddress ConvertAddress(ShippingAddress address)
    {
        var billingAddress = new BillingAddress (); // this is the problem - 3rd party lib
        ...
}
```

I'm working with 3rd party library and the only thing I can modify is AddressConverter class. By the way, BillingAddress() is a 3rd party library, 
 when decompiled shows this:

```
// decompiled code
public class BillingAddress : IOrderAddress
{
     public BillingAddress() : base(SomeSessionContext.Current.Class)
     {
     ...
```

The problem is that I can't create `new BillingAddress()` because it's values are taken from some session variable etc.

How can I test this? Any workarounds?

Comment: Where do you usually get instance of `BillingAddress`? does it have factory method/ static methods?

Comment: static method. no factory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't refactor to inject a BillingAddress into the static method, you can use Microsoft Fakes to test this.

Essentially you would add a Fakes Library for your 3rd Party DLL:

> In *Solution Explorer*, open your unit test project’s references and
>   select the reference to the assembly that contains the method you want
>   to fake. ... Choose **Add Fakes Assembly**.

[image]

Then you should be able to use a `ShimBillingAddress`. (Air code warning, I don't have access to your 3rd party lib :-) )

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
     // Arrange:
     YourThirdPartyLib.Fakes.ShimBillingAddress.SomeMethod = () => { return "some meaningful value"; };

     // Instantiate the component under test:
     var sut = new AddressConverter();

     // Act:
     var result = sut.ConvertAddress(someShippingAddress);

     // Assert: 
}
```

Quotes and instructions taken from [MSDN - Isolating Code Under Test with Microsoft Fakes // Getting started with shims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) and [MSDN - Using shims to isolate your application from other assemblies for unit testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx).

There is info on MSDN about the [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#BKMK_Fakes_naming_conventions) for shims that fakes generates, as it isn't always obvious.

Also, the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176369/unit-testing-using-shims-for-zipfile/34644546#34644546) has a walkthrough on setting up fakes for a system dll.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create BillingAddress inside AddressConverter. Use an extra argument for ConvertAddress or remove the static keyword and use an BillingAddressFactory to create a new instance of IOrderAddress.

Comment: taking it out, won't do any good since I can't create new BillingAddress() in my tests => this will still call Session stuff